# JSX callbacks are using old state values

Tags: reactjs

I've seen that this question has been already posted but I haven't been able to find anything suitable for my case.

I have this component:

```
const DefineConstraints = ({ data = [] }) => {
const CONSTRAINTS_EQUALITY_OPTIONS = [
  { value: '>', label: '>' },
  { value: '=', label: '=' },
  { value: '<', label: '<' },
  { value: '≤', label: '≤' },
  { value: '≥', label: '≥' }
]
const [rows, setRows] = useState([])
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

const addRow = () => {
  const row = {
    constraint: <Select options={data} style={{ width: '200px' }} />,
    condition: <Select options={CONSTRAINTS_EQUALITY_OPTIONS} style={{ width: '100px' }} />,
    value: <InputNumber />,
    key: counter,
    actions: <DeleteOutlined onClick={() => remove(counter)} />
  }

  setRows([...rows, row])
  setCounter(counter + 1)
}

const remove = id => console.log(rows)

return (
  <>
    <Space style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
      <strong>CONSTRAINTS</strong>
      <Button onClick={onClick}>Add</Button>
    </Space>
    <Table dataSource={rows} columns={columns} />
  </>
)
}
```

As you see, I have a callback placed on the event onClick of the delete icon (`DeleteOutlined`).
The callback return a wrong value in the `console.log(rows)` I guess it's the value of the state at the row generation time, In fact, if I generate 6 rows this is the result of the console log for each row

`[]`

`[{...}]`

`[{...}, {...}]`

`[{...}, {...}, {...}]`

etc...

How can I access the correct state?

Comment: Problem is because of a closure over the `rows` state. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Maybe a link to codesandbox demo? Using `useRef` hook, you can solve the problem but i need a minimal reproducible example to show you how you can use `useRef` hook to solve the problem.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but you may also want to change the call for setRows to `setRows(rows => [...rows, row])` and setCounter to `setCounter(count=>count + 1)` to make sure that two very fast clicks don't overwrite each other's state changes.

Comment: @Yousaf here https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-5t56w?file=/DefineConstraints.jsx

Comment: Here's the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-7d510?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of using `useRef` hook to solve the closure problem.